# Is there any way I can log network calls been triggered from the SDK/Android libraries in my app

Tags: android, okhttp, android-library, android-networking

I am developing an Android SDK/library, In here I am performing several network calls. But I don't want the Application developer(who uses my SDK) can log the network calls I performed from my sdk. As It violets our user privacy.

In more details, What I wanted to say, If the Application Developer add any network interceptor with okhttpClient. It should not log any network calls from my SDK. Thanks in advance.

So far I tried to add log interceptor with my OkhttpClientBuilder but no network calls been logged. But I need to be sure there is no other way the Application developer can log my network calls.

Comment: Hey Tareq, did you find any solution for this use case which you have mentioned? I am also working on android SDK. I have to release this SDK to public use, but I also prevent revealing network calls which are done by my SDK. As my SDK will run under the umbrella of other applications, I am worried how to secure JWT and other network info

Comment: As per my knowledge you can secure your network by using the ssl implementation for you api/network call so user can not your sdk apis in eg proxyman

Answer (score 1):

> If the Application Developer add any network interceptor with okhttpClient. It should not log any network calls from my SDK

So long as you are using your own `OkHttpClient` instance, rather than one that is given to you by an app using your library, you are in control of what interceptors are attached to that `OkHttpClient` instance.

It is still possible for developers to do things to log your network calls. For example, they could compile their app with a modified copy of OkHttp, one that logs whatever they want.